# CSS Flexbox: Use available space after reflow

Tags: html, css, web

I got the following situation:
My page contains a panel that looks like that in a normal situation.

```
Text 1                                     Text text lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="ui-g">
    <div class="ui-g-6">
        Text 1
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-6">
        Text text lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, on low resolutions, I want the columns to reflow to a single one what I accomplished by using flexbox:

```
.ui-g {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.ui-g > div {
    min-width: 180px;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This means: normally, both columns have a width of 50% (because of `ui-g-6`) and a min-width of 180px -> if the panel has a lower resolution than ~360px, the reflow happens.

My problem's the following:

When lowering the resolution, the page changes from

```
Text 1                                     Text text lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
```

to

```
Text 1                                     Text text lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
                                           lorem ipsum
```

and after the reflow:

```
Text 1                                                      
Text text lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum
```

As you can see, the content is now unnecessarily narrow, I'd prefer it to look like that:

```
Text 1                                                      
Text text lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
```

I know about flex-grow, but this overrides any `width` attribute and totally messes up my page layout on normal resolutions. Also, it didn't have the desired effect anyway.

Any tips are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Using `flex-basis` instead of `min-width` and adding `flex-grow` should get you there:

```css
.ui-g {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  outline: #0FF6 solid;
  outline-offset: 3px;
  margin: 1em;
}

.ui-g>div {
  flex-basis: 180px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: #F0F6 solid;
  outline-offset: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-g">
  <div class="ui-g-6">
    Text 1
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-6">
    Text text lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ui-g" style="width: 300px">
  <div class="ui-g-6">
    Text 1
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-6">
    Text text lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm cautiously optimistic - I found two small irregularities when using this approach, but it's probably just some other CSS that needs to be adjusted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood your question, but :

```
.ui-g {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.ui-g > div {
    min-width: 180px;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
  @media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    .ui-g {
      white-space: nowrap; /* text wont go to next line if it refactors */
    }
  }
```

Comment: you just copy-paste the above CSS what did you change in it?

Comment: white-space: nowrap,

Comment: white-space: nowrap; not make any difference,  you must check your code is working or not before answer I check it and not able to find any difference in the result.

Comment: I put it in codepen and it made a difference when resizing, which is what I understood he wanted from his question.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding I tried to upvote it but it's locked now!

Comment: That's fine, no problem. I just hope this is the answer he's looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not totally doing the trick for me: I'm not trying to prevent line breaks, they're fine (up to a certain limit), however when the space is so small that the reflow takes place, I want the (now unnecessary) line breaks from earlier to revert, since after reflowing, there's enough space to fit it into one line. From my page layout examples above, the second one is fine by me, only the third one bothers me and I'd prefer the fourth one. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: I edited my answer, hope this is more like you meant it, also, i couldnt really replicate the small browser, it won't allow me to go that small. But this should work. (If I haven't misunderstood you once again :D)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).